# How to change font of an embedded resource using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to get rid of a custom font that has been used for years. Due to regulations I need to replace this font with a common one. 
Anyways, I've tried to write a JUnit Test to change the font of a pdf using PDFBox.

This is what I have done:

```
@Test
public void changeFontOfAllPdfsToArial() throws Exception {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("src/test/broken_pdf.pdf"));     
    for(PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
        PDResources resources = page.getResources();
        for(COSName key : resources.getFontNames()) {
            PDFont font = resources.getFont(key);
            System.out.println(font.getFontDescriptor().getFontName());
            if(resources.getFont(key).toString().contains("CUSTOM")) {
            }
        }
    }

    document.save(new File(PDFs.get(0).getAbsolutePath() + "_test"));

}
```

Iterating through the list gives me all the fonts of the document.
I'm getting the COSName key of the resource, but how do I change the font of it? Thanks for your help!

€: Just to mention: The font is embedded.

Comment: `resource.put(key, font)` will do it. However this will only work for very simple cases, i.e. not a font subset, same encoding.

Comment: It doesn't work for me though. Overwriting the value kinda destroys the document. The part where the font is placed becomes gibberish. I guess it is a subset. Am I able to deduce the subset and set a font for it?

Comment: *"Am I able to deduce the subset and set a font for it?"* - the answer to both questions: it depends! It depends on how nice the software was which embedded the subset. Thus, please share a representative example pdf.

Comment: What is the name of the font? Does it have a "+" in it? Then it's a subset. Open such a file in PDFDebugger and look at the font table, this will show why it's so tricky.

Comment: The font is indeed named with a "+". It looks like this "AAAAAB + Custom-Regular". I can't really share a real example since the costumer is very sensitive about it. Also... The issue with the font is present to a larger amount of pdfs ( thousands ) and it is not guaranteed that they all behave the same way. I will inspect some documents with a richer pdf viewer first